# Filter Combobox Data in Java

Tags: java, swing, combobox

In java, let's say there are two jpanels, when I click button 'A' on Panle'1', it will show panel '2'. In panel '2', there are two comboboxes and I finished all necessary coding. But one thing to filter is combobox'1' will show only those data who has 'book'prefix. & combobox '2' will show only those without 'book prefix'. How should I filter it?

Answer (score 4):

The `ComboBoxModel` controls the content of your `JComboBox`. The only way to filter that I know of is to not have the unwanted values in your models. You can filter them out when creating the models.

Assuming you have all the desired values in a `List`, I would use the [GlazedLists](http://publicobject.com/glazedlists/) library. It provides observable lists and lets you do all kinds of interesting stuff with them, like filtering and sorting. Of particular interest in this case is `FilterList`: you supply it an `EventList` and a `Matcher` which decides how to filter the EventList. The FilterList acts like a view on the EventList, meaning that if you change the EventList, the FilterList will reflect this. With this FilterList, you can then make a `EventComboBoxModel` and use that as your model.