# Remove elements from a JComboBox within its listeners

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have a combobox, with certain elements within it, eg: "abc", "pqr", now when the user types "a", I wish to refresh the combobox and remove all its elements and then again add only those elements which start with the user string. (These elements are stored in a array)

I tried in to modify its elements in "addCaretListener" but it throws "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Attempt to mutate in notification" Exception

Is there a specific way to implement this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

consider using two [JComboBoxes](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) or [Autocompleted JTextField plus JComboBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255636/is-it-possible-to-have-an-autocomplete-using-jtextfield-and-a-jlist/7255918#7255918) (instead of your described request), there you have to get all highlighted Chars ( create only contructor to the same method as filtering Item(s) ) from [JTextField](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) and dynamically update [ComboBoxModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7387299/after-adding-items-dynamically-to-jcombobox-in-swing-those-values-are-not-appear/7388965#7388965)

Answer (score 2):

I think you create the AutoComplete combo see this example

http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/7633

or see this post

[Filter Combobox Data in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3633400/filter-combobox-data-in-java)

http://forums.devshed.com/delphi-programming-90/how-to-filter-combobox-items-on-onchangeevent-251852.html